# FFTW Wisdom Not Working

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, fft, fftw

I am attempting to use the Wisdom feature of FFTW to create FFTW plans quicker. The wisdom seems to be saving correctly and loading correctly as well, but it doesn't speed up the creation of subsequent runs. Also if I attempt to create a plan using the WISDOM_ONLY flag it returns a NULL plan letting me know that even though the call to load the wisdom worked correctly, it can't be used to make plans.

If I run the following code multiple times, the first time it will fail to load the wisdom file (because it doesn't exist), and on subsequent runs it will report that it loaded correctly. On each run, first or subsequent, creating the FFTW plans takes the same amount of time.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <omp.h>

#include "fftw3.h"

#define THREADS 4

int main ()
{
   LARGE_INTEGER li, li2;
   __int64 init, run;
   double freq;

   int Xfft = 384;
   int Yfft = 384;
   int iterations = 1000;
   fftwf_plan pFft[THREADS];

   QueryPerformanceFrequency ( &li );
   freq = (double)li.QuadPart / 1000000.0;

   // Malloc buffer
   fftwf_complex* arr[THREADS];

   for ( int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
   {
      arr[i] = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc ( sizeof(fftwf_complex) * Xfft * Yfft );
   }

   // Setup FFT plan
   QueryPerformanceCounter ( &li );

   if (fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename("fftw.wis") == 1 )
   {
      printf("SUCCESS!\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("FAILURE!\n");
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++ )
   {
      pFft[i] = fftwf_plan_dft_2d ( Xfft, Yfft, arr[i], arr[i], FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_PATIENT );
   }

   fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename("fftw.wis");

   QueryPerformanceCounter ( &li2 );
   init = li2.QuadPart - li.QuadPart;

   // Init array to random numbers
   for ( int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++ )
      for ( int j = 0; j < Xfft * Yfft; j++ )
      {
         arr[i][j][0] = (float)rand();
         arr[i][j][1] = (float)rand();
      }

   omp_set_num_threads(THREADS);

   // Perform FFTs
   QueryPerformanceCounter ( &li );

   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      int ID = omp_get_thread_num();

      #pragma omp for
      for ( int i = 0; i < iterations; i++ )
      {
         fftwf_execute ( pFft[ID] );
      }
   }

   QueryPerformanceCounter ( &li2 );
   run = li2.QuadPart - li.QuadPart;

   // Free Buffer / destroy plan
   for ( int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++ )
   {
      fftwf_destroy_plan ( pFft[i] );
      fftwf_free ( arr[i] );
   }

   printf ( "Plan creation time: %6.4f microseconds\n", (double)init / freq );
   printf ( "FFT execution time: %6.4f microseconds\n", (double)run  / freq / (double)iterations );

   system( "pause" );

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add, this is setup a little weird because it was used to make some measurements that were mimicking some code which was using multiple single-threaded FFTW plans that were being used at the same time in different threads (each was operating on a different data set).

Comment: Obligatory question:  What compiler are you using, and are you running an optimized build?

Comment: I'm using MSVC2010 with the FFTW dlls that were provided from their website. This happens under both debug mode with optimizations off and release mode with full optimizations.

Comment: How much time are you spending in each loop iteration?  You call `fftwf_plan_dft_2d()` four times, then `fftwf_execute()` four times.  And what's the difference between with and without wisdom if you use FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE?  Because FFTW_PATIENT really isn't all that patient, and 384x384 isn't that large of an FFT.  You're also counting the time it takes to import and export wisdom as part of the wisdom computation time.